# Must an interpolator exist with linearly independent basis functions?

Tags: regression, linear-algebra, splines, interpolation

I have data $(x_1,y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n) \in \mathbb  R^2$ and the $x_i$ are distinct and increasing. I want to interpolate the $y_i$ with a function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^Na_i h_i(x)
$$
where the $h_i$ are known basis functions. I know that fitting this involves computing the $n\times N$ matrix $H$ where
$$
H_{ij} = h_j(x_i)
$$
and then solving $y = Ha$. I'll take $N=n$ so that $H$ is square.

My question: even if the $h_i$ are linearly independent, am I guaranteed to have $H$ be invertible? I think not, because for example if I do $h_1(x) = x$ and $h_2(x) = |x|$, with a domain of $[-1,1]$, say, then if
$$
a_1h_1 + a_2h_2 = 0
$$
I can evaluate my basis functions at $\pm 1$ to get 
$$
a_1 + a_2 = 0 \\
a_1 - a_2 = 0
$$
which mean $a_1=a_2=0$ so these $h_i$ are linearly independent. But if I observe $x_1 = \frac 14$ and $x_2 = \frac 34$, for example, then
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 14 & \frac 34 \\ \frac 14 & \frac 34\end{bmatrix}
$$
which isn't invertible. So linear independence doesn't seem sufficient for constructing an interpolating basis, but what is? I feel like when I read about interpolators with basis functions I always see discussions of linear independence but I haven't noticed this issue until it happened to me (i.e. an unexpectedly singular $H$)

Comment: You are right: independence is not sufficient. This question is discussed in Chap 1 of the book by W. Cheney and W. Light  [A course in Approximation Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-101), a good reference.

Comment: @Yves thank you, that's perfect! If you'd like to post an answer giving the main result I'd be happy to accept it